# body.addEventListener('load') не работает

Tags: javascript

Почему в скрипте работает запись

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    console.log('onload')
}
```

и не работает

```
document.body.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('event load')
})
```

Принципиально нужно повесить обработчик на body, а не на window

Comment: Немного погуглив, пришел выводу, что событие `load` реализует только объект `window`. А чем обусловлена такая странная принципиальность? У вас нет доступа к переменной `window`?

Comment: Я так предполагаю, что на момент когда вешается этот обработчик, событие уже или сработало или `body` еще не существует и повесить обработчик не на что.

Comment: @vihtor, если посмотреть в консоле, то у любого элемента есть событие `onload`, но... если вешать обработчик на элемент пока его еще нет - будет ошибка. А если вешать обработчик  на элемент, когда он есть - то `onload` уже прошло

Comment: Принципиальность в том что содержимое body формируется скриптом, нужно отследить момент когда содержимое вставлено в документ и все ресурсы загружены. window.onload в данном случае не срабатывает

Answer (score 4):

если посмотреть в консоле, то у любого элемента есть событие `onload`, но... если вешать обработчик на элемент пока его еще нет - будет ошибка. А если вешать обработчик на элемент, когда он есть - то `onload` уже прошло. Имхо)

Comment: Да но document.body.onload = function() {} работает. Разве addEventListener('load') это не тоже событие? Просто обработчик записан в другой форме